# Validar formulário e inserir em Base de Dados com PHP

Tags: php, sql, formulário, validação

Olá

Sou ainda um principiante em PHP e estagnei ao validar o formulário de contacto do meu site.

Conclui a validação do lado do cliente usando Javascript, mas do lado do servidor é  que ainda não conclui a tarefa, dai pedir a vossa ajuda.

Tenho o formulário em HTML abaixo:

```
<form id="form" name="contactForm" method="post" action="php/Form.php">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Your name</label> 
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="40" placeholder="Write your Name"   >
                <span class="error"><?php echo $nameError;  ?></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Your email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="user_mail" placeholder="email@example.com">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $emailError;  ?></span> 
            </div>                
            <div>
                <label for="topic">Select Topic</label>
                <select id="topic" name="topic">
                    <option selected disabled hidden value="">Choose a Topic</option>
                    <option value="link">Site Link</option>
                    <option value="copyright">Copyright</option>
                    <option value="errors">Site/Article errors</option>
                    <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $topicError;  ?></span>
            </div>                
            <div>
                <label for="msg">Your message</label>
                <textarea id="msg" name="user_message" placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $msgError;  ?></span>
            </div>                
            <div class="button">
                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  value="true">Submit</button> 
                <span class="success"></span>
            </div>
        </form>
```

E em formulário_contactos.php escrevi o seguinte codigo:

```
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "site_comboios";


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['user_mail'];
$topic = $_POST['topic'];
$msg = $_POST['user_message'];


if( isset( $_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty( $name) || isset($name) ) {
    $nameError = "Name is required" ;
}

if(empty( $email) || isset($email)) {
    $emailError = "Email is required";
} elseif(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailError = "Please insert a correct email address";  
}  

if(empty( $topic) || isset($topic) ) {
    $topicError = "Please choose a topic";
} 

if(empty( $msg) || isset($msg) ) {
    $msgError = "Let us know your opinion";
}
}

//Create connection to database
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//check connection
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo 'Error connecting to database';
}

//Prepared Statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO contacts(Nome, Email, Topico,  Mensagem)  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)" );
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $email, $topic, $msg);
$stmt->execute();
```

O que acontece ao premir o botão "Submit", é este ser submetido mesmo sem quaisquer dados inseridos! (este teste é sempre feito com o Javascript desligado, é claro)

Não faz qualquer validação e um novo registo é sempre criado na base de dados.

O que estou a fazer mal na parte da validação?

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Analisando seu código, é visível a falta de validação de quando deve, ou não, ser inserido um novo registro.

Veja bem, você valida `input` a `input`. Mas não valida se deve ou não ser inserido, apenas insere.

Seguindo por base a sua validação, a solução mais rápida seria substituir as variáveis de erro por um array (é mais fácil para validar).

```
$errorList = [];

if(empty($_POST['user_mail'])) {
    $errorList["emailError"] = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST['user_mail']);
}
```

E validar se existem mensagens de erro:

```
if (count($errorList) == 0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO formulario_contactos (Nome, Email, Topico, Mensagem)
    VALUES ('$name', '$email' , '$topic' , '$mensagem')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo 'Your message has been successfully sent';
    } else {
        echo 'Error'. $sql . $conn->error;    
    }
} 
else 
{
    /** tratamento de erros **/
}
```

Isso resolveria o problema de validação ao submeter o seu formulário. Entretanto, seu código não possui só esse problema. O primeiro é que ele é vulnerável. A função `mysqli_real_escape_string` não é para proteger seu código, apenas para realizar o escape de alguns caracteres, utilize *prepared statements* no lugar. Você pode ler mais sobre SQL injection no link abaixo. Existe um tópico apenas sobre `mysqli_real_escape_string`.
https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection

Realizando o procedimento acima mencionado, a função `test_input` se torna inútil. Excetuando-se apenas `trim` que pode ser utilizado em alguns casos que realmente não podem ocorrer espaços extras.

A sanitização que você está realizando tem como intuito a exibição, nada além. Não é uma segurança, logo, além de `prepared statements`, não há nenhuma necessidade a mais para o seu código. Sanitizações para exibição devem ser realizadas na hora de exibir e não na inserção.